# iPhone default map app open with current userlocation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, location, cllocationmanager

In my app, on button click I am opening default iphone map  application as follows:-

```
NSString *mystr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@",userlocation,desti_latlong];
NSURL *myurl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mystr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myurl];
```

In that desti_latlong is destination latitude longitude string and userlocation is user's latitude longitude string found by corelocation(location manager).

But I want to add source location as "Current Location" string on this API .
If we use Iphone defualt map app directly we can give current location it will popup in blue string Can I make this from my app so that If user moves location updated on map.

thanx for any  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OHh yes i was writing directly Current Location but I need to write Current+Location.solved that

```
NSString *mystr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=Destination"];
NSURL *myurl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mystr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myurl];
```